# time meridiem was given by device local language instead of am/pm

Tags: java, android

```
 Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a").format(currentDate);
```

Now the time i got 11:40 午前 instead of 11:40 am.How to avoid taking device default language in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use constructor which takes Locale as its argument.
Check
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-

Your code would go like this:

```
time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a",Locale.ENGLISH).format(currentDate);
```